# Splitting Data - String.split parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and am trying to format some data. I have data in the following format:

```
"Matt Forte : 17.8C.J. Anderson : 16.5Jamaal Charles : 16.4"
```

what is the best way to split it as follows? 
string.split(), what would I put in the parenthesis?

```
Matt Forte : 17.8
C.J. Anderson : 16.5
Jamaal Charles : 16.4
```

My code so far:

```
 var playersAndPoints = $('.items').text();
            var playersAndPoints = JSON.stringify(playersAndPoints);
            var re = /Points\s\(PPR\)/gi;
            var formattedPlayers = playersAndPoints.replace(re, " ");
            for(var i = 0; i<formattedPlayers.length; i++){
                if ((typeof(formattedPlayers[i]) === 'number') && (typeof(formattedPlayers[++i]) === 'letter')
                {
                    formattedPlayers.split(formattedPlayers[i])
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: updating to show that

Comment: You're probably going to need a Regex, since there isn't a clear delineation between `17.8` and `C.J`, for instance.

Comment: You could try `.substring()`.

Comment: This will get you close, but I don't have time to finish figuring it out. `.split(/(?=\d[A-z])/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be processed a bit simpler I think

First, I can see all player data ends up with a number (+ optional decimal point)

A [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that would match this could be

```
var re = /[^0-9]+[0-9]+(?:\.?[0-9]+)?/g
```

Let's use it now:

```
re.match("Matt Forte : 17C.J. Anderson : 16.5Jamaal Charles : 16.4");
// ["Matt Forte : 17", "C.J. Anderson : 16.5", "Jamaal Charles : 16.4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Regex that gets the job done:

```
var data = 'Matt Forte : 17C.J. Anderson : 16.5Jamaal Charles : 16.4'
var sorted = data.match(/(\D)+:\s(\d|\.)+/g)
console.log(sorted)
// [ 'Matt Forte : 17.8',
//   'C.J. Anderson : 16.5',
//   'Jamaal Charles : 16.4' ]
```